# Is there a way to know the health of a vehicle without entering it?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a way to know the health of a vehicle without entering it? I know that if the vehicle is on fire, then its health must be very low. But apart from that?

And as an engineer, is there a way to know the current health?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For engineer:
If you repair it you will see an round icon of the current health and total health, in the middle of the vehicle. However this is not clearly visible with all the icons in BF.

Comment: You actually have to be next to the unit and using the Repair Tool to see this value though. You can not tell from a distance (Safe behind cover) what the status of the vehicle health is. (AFAIK)

Comment: Indeed, thats what I mean with "If you repair it". It is not possible to detect from a distance, apart from looking at the smoke coming out of the vehicle.

Comment: "in the middle of the vehicle", you mean in the middle of the "3D model"? Or the middle of the HUD? Or in the middle of the vehicle icon on the minimap? I can't seem to find it (I must be blind I guess). Can you post a screenshot? :)

Comment: 3D model, it is hardly visible. Sometimes you can't see because the repair tool 'sparks' overlay it. Try moving around the vehicle.

Comment: I find that sometimes the round icon never shows up for me. It seems to be buggy. It's rather frustrating because I can't tell if I'm done repairing my vehicle, though I think the sound and the sparks change somewhat when the vehicle becomes fully repaired.

Comment: However, sometimes (I'm not sure under what exact circumstances) as you aim at an occupied vehicle you get a health bar underneath the name of the driver: this is the vehicle's health.